# Multiple bx-slider with single pager manage all in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Want to manage the 3 slider with same pager

i had tried this code but its not Working

```
<script language="javascript">
$('.mobile_left_mble,.mobile_right_mble,.text_btn').bxSlider({
  //pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
  pager:true,
  controls: false,
  touchEnabled : true,
    mode: 'fade',
    easing: 'swing',
  auto :true,
});
$('.mobile_left_mble,.mobile_right_mble').each(function(i){
        alert (i);
        slider_array[i] = $(this).bxSlider({pager:false});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do. First of all, in my JS file I would initialize all my 3 elements, in this case 'mobile_left_mble, mobile_right_mble and text_btn' with a unique BxSlider call. I would store each call in three unique variables.

```
var mySlider1;
var mySlider2;
var mySlider3;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    mySlider1 = $('.mobile_left_mble').bxSlider({
       pager:false
    });

    mySlider2 = $('.mobile_right_mble').bxSlider({
       pager:false
    });

    mySlider3 = $('.text_btn').bxSlider({
       pager:false
    });
});
```

Once this is done, you can create your custom pager in your HTML file. Each pager-item, whether they be 'li, a href , div' (you decide), will need to have an indication to determine which slide to go to. What you can do is add inline custom attributes to your pager-item. This attribute would be, for example: data-slide="x", x being the slide index (according to BxSlider documentation, 0 being slide 1, etc).

```
<ul class="one-pager-to-rule-them-all">
    <li><a class="pager-item" data-slide="0">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="pager-item" data-slide="1">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="pager-item" data-slide="2">3</a></li>
    <li><a class="pager-item" data-slide="3">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Back to your JS file, I would create an OnClick event for my pager-items. BxSlider is a great plugin and provides all sort of nifty and useful callbacks, methods and events you can use to your advantage. That way, by clicking a pager element, you will be able to retrieve the slide index value with jquery and call BxSlider's own 'goToSlide(x)' method. You will need to call that method on each of the previously declared variables in which we stored our slider initialization. Take the time to read [bxSlider documentation](http://bxslider.com/options).

```
var toSlide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
mySlider1.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider2.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider3.goToSlide(toSlide);
```

By doing this, all sliders will be controlled by the same pager.

Check out my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrQGL/)

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: thanku for the help. This code is working well but genrating one problem.
After click on the .one-pager-to-rule-them-all li in browser, the active class remain on the same li n slider stop working further.
Please give suggestion for this problem

Comment: $('a.bx-pager-link').click ( function() {
var toSlide = $(this).attr('data-slide-index');
mySlider1.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider2.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider3.goToSlide(toSlide);},
function(){
 var toSlide = $(this).attr('data-slide-index');
 mySlider1.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider2.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider3.goToSlide(toSlide);
 return false;
});
});
If we used this code instread of
var toSlide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
mySlider1.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider2.goToSlide(toSlide);
mySlider3.goToSlide(toSlide); then it perform perfectly.
Thanku for your contribution IndieRok.

Comment: Sorry, i was away from my computer for the weekend. Have you been able to make it work to your liking? And in what browser did the problem occur?

Comment: What browser version also?

Comment: Ok, and does it work now? If not, do you have a test /dev version online that shows the behaviour? I could try to find the source of the problem

Comment: Yes now it works perfectly and No i d'not know about the text /dev version online. Can you please give me detail about that for my future help. Thankyou